# Function to extract a segment from a container

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Let's say I used `remove(v.begin(), v.end(), value)` where `v` is a `vector` or some other container class from the standard library.

This function moves the undesired values to the end of the container.Is there any function from any standard library that chops off that end of the container, effectively reducing its size? (This situation with `remove` is just an example, such "extraction" operation would have many other different cases and situations).

The function would be something like this: `chop(new_begin, new_end)` where `new_begin` and `new_end` are iterators pointing to the limits of the desired new container.

I could easily do this with a couple of lines but it seems like a good idea if there was a function that already did that. I took a glance at the `<algorithm>` header but I didn't find such tool.

Comment: This necessarily requires a modification *of the container*, so you can't use iterators alone. You can use e.g. the `erase` member function of many containers. This leads to the rather well-known [erase-remove technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom): `myVector.erase(std::remove(begin(myVector), end(myVector), end(myVector));`

Comment: *"effectively reducing its side"* Is probably a typo?

Comment: `std::remove` doesn't move the undesired values to the end of the container. It shifts elements that _aren't to be removed_ to the beginning of the range. The elements past the end of the resulting range have unspecified values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::copy` that takes an iterator to the begin and end of the sequence to be copied. This way you can copy the elements within the specified range to a new container. You can also use a combination of two calls to erase, but for some containers removing elements that are not last is not efficient(e.g. for `std::vector`) and so this approach will be slower.